# Passing GLSurfaceView context to a thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, opengl-es, openglcontext

I want my GL Renderer to be set to "DIRTY" and use a thread to control the FPS but for some reason the `requestRender` call seems to be skipped over all together. I have a feeling this could be something to do with the thread not getting the proper context. Does anybody know good practice for passing `GLSurfaceView` context to other threads?

Here is my thread:

```
public class GameLoop extends Thread {


    private GLSurfaceView myGLSurfaceView;
    private final static int maxFPS = 30;
    private final static int maxFrameSkips = 5;
    private final static int framePeriod = 1000 / maxFPS;

    public static boolean running;
    public final static String TAG = "input";

    public GameLoop(){
        myGLSurfaceView = MyLaunchActivity.getMyGLSurfaceView();
    }

@Override
public void run() {

    running = MyLaunchActivity.getRunning();
    long beginTime;
    long timeDiff;
    int sleepTime;
    int framesSkipped;


    sleepTime = 0;
    while (running) {
        running = MyLaunchActivity.getRunning();
        //Log.d(TAG, "gameRunning");
        beginTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        framesSkipped = 0;
        GameLogic.update();
        myGLSurfaceView.requestRender();
        //Log.d(TAG, "rendered");
        timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - beginTime;
        sleepTime = (int)(framePeriod - timeDiff);

        if (sleepTime > 0) {
            try{
                Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                //Log.d(TAG, "sleeping" + String.valueOf(sleepTime));
            }catch(InterruptedException e){}
        }

        while(sleepTime < 0 && framesSkipped < maxFrameSkips){
            GameLogic.update();
            sleepTime += framePeriod;
            framesSkipped++;
            Log.d(TAG, "Frames Skipped");
        }




}
}


}
```

And here is the constructor for my surface view ...

```
 public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
            myGLSurfaceRenderer = new MyGLSurfaceRenderer();
    setRenderer(myGLSurfaceRenderer);
    setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
            Log.d(TAG, "GLSurfaceViewed");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myGLSurfaceView = MyLaunchActivity.getMyGLSurfaceView();
```

Some questions about your code :

- How do you set the context ?
- Did you check that you create the GameLoop object after initializing the MyGLSurfaceView returned by MyLaunchActivity.getMyGLSurfaceView() ?

The first thing you can do is adding a catch clause for Exception in your run() method to see if there is any problem that explain why the method isn't called.

Comment: I create my glSurfaceView in onCreate and my loop starts in onResume so yes the loop starts after initialization. I'm not sure where the context gets set but I set the GLSufaceView using `glSurfaceView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this, null);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);` in MyLaunchActivity. The xml layout includes a FrameLayout with the glSurfaceView

Comment: You can try to rename the run() method into runTry() and add a run() method : run(){ try{runTry();}catch(Exception ex){ Log.d(TAG, "Exception: "+ex); } }

Comment: You can also add a log message after the running loop to see if the loop is finished. And also another log message as the first instruction of the loop to see each iteration start.

Comment: Would there be an exception to catch if the process doesn't crash? because the process doesn't crash, the requestRender seems to just be skipped over.